# Google Sheets removing duplicate data based on date and data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I apologize if I've overlooked any similar questions that have been answered regarding this issue. I spent a few hours looking through as many questions as I could, but none have gotten close to helping me resolve this particular problem...

I'm working with Google Sheets along with a form to help populate a chart that gives us the locations of equipment based on serial numbers (screenshots below).

The chart is arranged by building names that have the potential to house equipment in column A and equipment types in columns B-H. The form attached to this chart sends its submissions to a second sheet, which is where I draw the data from. I am using MAXIFS to populate the

The problem I'm having is that when a new form submission is entered into the second sheet regarding the movement of a piece of equipment that has previously been moved, the chart will list that equipment in two places instead of simply listing it in the newest location based on the newest form submission. Obviously an item can't be in two places at once.

[chart sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg3EX.png)
[form sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKBRE.png)

As you can see from the screenshots above, in the "chart sheet" it shows 9006 in three different locations. In the "form sheet" it shows that 9006 was moved from LSB to HSB and then to Admin (in column D).

What I'm looking to do is remove all previous submissions regarding a piece of equipment and only using the newest submission in the chart sheet so that it shows me that piece of equipment in only its newest location. I've tried using UNIQUE, FILTER, and QUERY to try to get the results I'm looking for, but to no avail.

Again, I apologize if a similar question has been answered previously. If any further information based on this question is needed, I'll gladly provide it. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the "form sheet" with the properly spaced timestamp column.

[form sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPqFV.png)

EDIT 2: The equipment are labeled with similar serial numbers but are proceeded by different letters (ex: X9006 and B9006 have similar numbers but are separate pieces of equipment because of their preceding letters.) The serial numbers are listed in column C of the "form sheet" and the preceding letters are in column B of the "form sheet". The answer from player0 works wonderfully, but only considers the serial numbers without regard to the letters in column B. Some buildings may contain different pieces of equipment with the same serial numbers, but have different letters. I would like for the chart to have the ability to list the same serial number on the "chart sheet" only if the preceding letters are different. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The time stamp is clipped down to the minutes is the same, include your sheets or a table if you can or screenshot  of the data with properly sized cells

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:D; 1; 0); 9^9; 2; 3; 1)
```

Comment: This almost works completely as I was hoping for! The only issue I'm having (which I didn't properly describe in my question) is that the chart now only allows one particular serial number to be listed anywhere on the sheet. The equipment have similar serial numbers preceded by a differing letter (X, B, F, etc.). The chart will only recognize one single serial number without regard to the letter in column B of the form sheet. I will edit my question above to include this as well. Thank you for your response!